# Gstreamer 1.20 or 1.22.65 - Seekable Pipeline with audio not working

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp-server

Using version 1.22.5.
I currently have the following dash manifest that I'm including in a pipeline inside the rtsp server:

```
Properties:
  Duration: 2:01:58.000000000
  Seekable: yes
  Live: no
  container #0: application/dash+xml
    container #-1: MPEG-2 Transport Stream
      video #1: H.264 (High Profile)
        Stream ID: 68aadcef81c48500f66e4ce9b166ae16c69aac2bda4b1a665aae064ceb2bd265/video_00:1/00000201
        Width: 1280
        Height: 720
        Depth: 24
        Frame rate: 25/1
        Pixel aspect ratio: 1/1
        Interlaced: false
        Bitrate: 0
        Max bitrate: 0
      audio #2: AC-3 (ATSC A/52)
        Stream ID: 68aadcef81c48500f66e4ce9b166ae16c69aac2bda4b1a665aae064ceb2bd265/video_00:1/00000303
        Language: und
        Channels: 2 (front-left, front-right)
        Sample rate: 48000
        Depth: 32
        Bitrate: 0
        Max bitrate: 0
```

In my first pipeline I have audio but in the check_seekable method of the rtsp-media.c class it doesn't understand how seekable:

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc ssl-strict=false location=http://localhost/Manifest.mpd?     \
     ! dashdemux \
     ! queue ! tsdemux name=demux mpegtsmux name=mux alignment=7 \
     ! queue ! tee name=t \
     t. ! queue ! parsebin ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 \
     t. ! queue ! udpsink host=X.X.X.X port=1939 \
     demux. ! queue ! h264parse ! mux. \
     demux. ! queue ! ac3parse ! mux.
```

in my second pipeline option it allows seek in the stream but I don't have the audio demux:

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc ssl-strict=false location=http://localhost/Manifest.mpd \
         ! dashdemux ! queue ! tsdemux name=video_0324 \
         ! queue ! tee name=t t. \
   ! queue ! parsebin ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 t. \
         ! queue ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! mpegtsmux     ! udpsink host=X.X.X.X port=1939 auto-multicast=true
```

I don't understand the reason, I need a pipeline with audio that allows seek, I tried several options without using encoder without success, can you help me please?

obs: I need the udpsink to remain like this because in addition to sending it by rtsp, I want to forward it to a separate udp